# Plot chart with CSV files containing labels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a function that plots a chart from a `CSV` file that contains labels:

```
LVL,Highscore
2,6013
2,5934
1,132
3,9560
4,13406
```

This is the code snippet I tried:

```py
from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np
import csv

def plot():
    style.use('ggplot')

    x, y = np.loadtxt(
        'highscore.csv',
         unpack=True,
         skiprows=1,
         usecols=1,
         delimiter=','
    )

plot()
```

And this is the traceback error I'm getting:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/FinalYearProject/anothertest.py", line 28, in <module>
    plot()
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/FinalYearProject/anothertest.py", line 18, in plot
    x, y = np.loadtxt('highscore.csv', unpack=True,
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FinalYearProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1148, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FinalYearProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 992, in read_data
    vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FinalYearProject\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 992, in <listcomp>
    vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I attempted to resolve it by using the parameter `usecols=1` and `skiprows=1`, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I completely understand your question, but I don't think you need usecols.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x, y = np.loadtxt('highscore.csv', unpack=True,  skiprows=1, delimiter=',')

>>> print(x)

[2., 2., 1., 3., 4.]

>>> print(y)

[ 6013.,  5934.,   132.,  9560., 13406.]
```

You can then proceed to plot the data. I am not sure which plot you expect, but a scatter plot seems most suitable here

```py
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> from matplotlib import style

>>> plt.style.use('ggplot')

>>> plt.scatter(x, y)
>>> plt.show()
```

Which will make this plot:

[image]

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I have managed to plot a graph with your suggested code. Thanks, but my intention is to have my x value set as LVL and y values set as Highscore... how do i specify that?

Comment: I have just edited the example to include a scatter plot. I think it should address your second question, as well as use `unpack=True` as you suggested in your original post.

Comment: Based on your comment, I think that's what I wanted... thanks. I have noticed that you're using collab/jupyter , currently Im using Pycharm and the plot is not showing up anymore. I know this has gone off topic, but i'll keep u updated.

Comment: The last line `plt.show()` is essential to make the plot. Have you included this line?

Comment: Thanks, by importing ```import matplotlib.pyplot as plt``` it worked. Thank u so much!